# How can I bottom align a div that can grow and cause it's container to scroll

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to make this layout happen without javascript.

I have a parent div and a child div that contains content which keeps being appended.  I want the child to be bottom aligned inside the parent and grow vertically.  I also want **the parent div to scroll** when the height of the child > height of parent.

[image: Child expands from the bottom, causing parent to scroll]

The first part is pretty easy with:

```
#child { position:absolute; bottom: 0 }
```

The second part is difficult because absolutely positioned elements are outside of the content-flow and won't trigger scrolling.

The parent div spans the entire height of the browser window *(which I don't know at design-time)*

Comment: Any chance you could put your example up on jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle with-out the bottom alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/epgdn/1/  I'm trying to achieve bottom alignment when the child is smaller and auto-scroll when it's bigger than the parent.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*Edited to show that it is possible*

Turns out it **IS possible** to provide the dynamic layout described **without using javascript**. There is a way (using just CSS) to have a div bottom aligned that causes scrolling when it overflows it's parent.

**The trick** is to make the scrolling happen on the child, setting it's max-height to 100% (i.e. the parents height) and then bottom aligning the child with `position:absolute;`.  You only need to make sure the parent has `position:relative or absolute`.

Here is the simple CSS to make it work:

```
#parent{
    position:absolute;
    /* these parts are obviously not necessary */
    width:500px;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}
#child{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    /* this is the key */
    max-height:100%;
}
```

This is reflected in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epgdn/5/  simply resize the run-window until the child is bigger than the parent and the parent will scroll appropriately.

Comment: The scrollbars still show up even when the content is smaller than the container. So if the content is half of the parents height, there will be vertical scrollbars half of the height.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with CSS alone. If you position the child at `top:0`, you'd be fine since the page is being processed from top down (so do the scroll bars).

```
body { font-size:1.2em; height:50%; color:#735005; }
div { margin:0; padding:0; }
#parent {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%; max-height:400px;
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    }
#child, #child2 {    /* #child2 is STRICTLY here to illustrate the desired effect */
    border:1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    }
#child2 { visibility:hidden; top:0; }

  <div id="parent">
     <div id="child">scroll scroll scroll ... scroll scroll scroll scroll</div>
     <div id="child2">scroll scroll scroll ... scroll scroll scroll scroll</div>
  </div>
```

Obviously, you don't want to hard code duplicate code for a UI effect. Server-/client-side scripting would be needed.